# Do views duplicate data or they only create an index?

Tags: nosql, couchdb, couchdb-2.0

I'm learning about CouchDB, and I don't get it: When I create a view, does the view copy the data that's inside the `emit` function or it only creates a new index based on it?

For example, let's suppose I have a database with documents like this one:

```json
{
    "name": "Bob",
    "age": 30
}
```

My view would be something like:

```js
function (doc) {
    emit(doc.name, doc.age);
}
```

Will CouchDB create a copy of every document (the emitted fields) and the view index when the view is executed for the first time? Or will it create only an index?

Answer (score 1):

With that map function, CouchDB will create a B-tree index based on `doc.name` with value `doc.age` and also it will store `doc._id` somewhere there. So it won't duplicate whole `doc` but will store those fields and perhaps something else in the index data.